# How to get a part of an image and use it as a separate image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

I have a tileset but all the tiles are in one image. I want to get every tile in some kind of bitmap or image array.
Is there some kind of method that does that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) , Here we can set [PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) of new image and the size of the rectangle

```
// Create a Bitmap object from a file.
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Grapes.jpg");

// Clone a portion of the Bitmap object.
Rectangle cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
Bitmap cloneBitmap = myBitmap.Clone(cloneRect, myBitmap.PixelFormat);

// Draw the cloned portion of the Bitmap object.
e.Graphics.DrawImage(cloneBitmap, 0, 0);
```

Comment: What is this PixelFormat for?